# Draw labels on top of stacked Bar char using android mp charts

Tags: android, charts, label, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I want to draw stacked bar chart on my android app using mp charts library.

I want to label like below , on top of all stacks and is displayed when clicked on each stack.

[image]

But i want display labels for all x values and when clicked anywhere on the chart.

[image]

Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. Check the sample code on https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample

Answer (score 0):

Add this code where you are customizing your bar dataset:

```
barDataSet.setDrawValues(true);
```